# Pythonでのオブジェクト指向について質問致します。

Tags: python3

いつもお世話になっております。Python初心者です。

現在、オブジェクト指向を学習しており、リンクのコードを写経させてもらったのですが
実行できません。（エラーも出ません）
リンク[Pythonにおけるオブジェクト指向](https://sasakiyuki.github.io/posts/python_object_oriented/#%E5%AE%9F%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9-%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B)
こちらの「[memo] クラスの命名規則」に書いてあるコードをそのまま写経して
自分のPycharmで実行しようとしても何も出力されません。
どうすれば、こちらのリンク先に書いてあるような出力結果である
Name: クイバタ
Luck: 99
と出力されますか？　お力をお貸し下さい。よろしくお願いします。

```
class Monster:
    def display(self):

        print("Name:", self.name)
        print("Luck:", self.luck)

monster = Monster()
monster.name = "クイバタ"
monster.luck = 99
monster.display()
```

Comment: PyCharm ではなく macOS のコマンドラインから実行していますが、問題なく出力されます。Python コード自体の問題ではないはずです。

Comment: お騒がせして申し訳ございませんでした。違うファイルを開いておりました。